# Как проверить существует ли уже база данных mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть инсталяционный скрипт, нужно проверять существует ли уже база данных с заданным именем и вообще возможно ли создание бд (на некоторых хостингах стоит ограничение). Собственно в этом и вопрос, как это реализовать используя mysql.

Comment: Обычно в дампах пишется что-то вроде IFEXIST, проверить возможность можно попыткой. Посмотрите синтаксис SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создавать базу данных только в случае если она еще не существует:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DBName;
```

Для проверки прав пользователя есть команда ([Описание](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html)):

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER
```